# How to convert a classification tree plot with gridGraphics

Tags: r, gridview, plot, tree

I have a classification tree (CART) estimated using rpart:

```
library(rpart)
treefit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis,
          control = rpart.control(cp = 0.001))
```

I plot the tree using the command **fancyRpartPlot** of *rattle*:

```
require(rattle)
fancyRpartPlot(treefit)
```

and then I try to convert the plot to the same result drawn with *grid* using the **grid.echo** command of the package *gridGraphics*.

```
library(gridGraphics)
grid.echo()
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

I try a different tool for visualizing the tree, the package *rpart.plot* :

```
library(rpart.plot)
rpart.plot(treefit)
grid.echo()
```

and again:

```
Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

I get error messages from **grid.echo** also when trying to convert plots of trees generated by *party*, *RWeka* and *Rgraphviz*. 
The command seems to be able to convert only plots generated by *rpart*:

```
plot(treefit)
text(treefit)
grid.echo()
grid.ls()

graphics-plot-1-xlab-1
graphics-plot-1-ylab-1
graphics-plot-1-text-1
graphics-plot-1-lines-1
graphics-plot-1-text-2
graphics-plot-1-text-3
```

Unfortunately, these plots are raw and not pleasant.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to provide a full solution but at least some comments and alternatives:

`fancyRpartPlot()` from `rattle` and `rpart.plot()` from `rpart.plot` are not that different. Internally, the former calls the latter (or actually its sibling function `prp()` from the same package). So it is not surprising the both lead to the same problems. However, I'm not sure how to solve that error.

The fact that the plots from `party` (or better its successor package `partykit`) and `RWeka` cannot be converted is not so surprising. They are already drawn with `grid`! You can also use the `partykit` infrastructure to draw your `rpart` tree:

```
library("partykit")
plot(as.party(treefit))
```

[image: rpart-tree-partykit-plot]

Comment: Dear Achim, your comments are useful and suggest me a way for generating an interactive tree using **gridSVG**. Thank you!

Comment: @achim-zeileis, thanks for the great contribution to the statistical community! Do you know, is there any way to convert `party` tree to `rpart` representations?

Comment: No, we haven't tried to do that because the `rpart` format is really specific to the CART algorithm and cannot easily represent information used in other tree algorithms. You would probably be able to find workarounds for the important bits but we always felt it wasn't worth the effort (for us). And to the best of my knowledge no one else has attempted to write such an interface.